# RaiseError not logging Error message into DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, error-messages

I have a requirement to cancel a send if certain conditions are not met. My current code cancels the send, but does not log the conditions. According to the [RaiseError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/raiseerror.htm) Documentation, the last term (`boolean`)

> Indicates whether the function records information to data extensions
>   before error occurs, even if the process skips the subscriber. A value
>   of 1 retains information written to data extensions before the error
>   occurs, even if the subscriber is skipped. A value of 0 does not
>   retain information recorded before the error. This parameter refers to
>   inserted, updated, upserted, or deleted information via AMPscript.

so if my understanding is right, putting a value of `1` here so log the error.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
SET @rows2 = LookUpOrderedRows('ENT.Presend Agreement Log',1,'DateAdded Desc','email_name',emailname_) 
IF RowCount(@rows2) == 0 
    THEN 
        SET @Message ="Loren Ipsum"

/*Should this be an upsert??*/

UpsertDE('ENT.Presend Agreement Error Log',1,
           'email_name',emailname_,
           'error_message',@Message)
RaiseError(@Message, false,1)
ENDIF
```

Would appreciate any pointers here

Comment: Your RaiseError() function is only using 3 parameters. The documentation says to set the 5th parameter in order to retain the information recorded? Looks like you are just setting the API Error Code to be 1?

Comment: @TravisNaughton you could be right..but 3 and 4 are strings...if thought putting 1 as a boolean would bypass them since they are optional

Comment: The documentation is a bit all over the place. It says that it should be boolean but the example says to use an integer as a boolean. I wouldn't have thought it would handle bypassing variables, but will be interested to see if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AMPScript does not have any named parameters, so all parameters must be passed by position. In this case, the RaiseError function has 5 parameters and you are trying to specify the 5th without specifying the 3rd or 4th. This means that your code is raising API error code 1 and then ignoring the next two optional parameters.

I believe the convention to ignore optional positional parameters in AMPScript is to use an empty variable, typically @null. This means your code to raise the error should be:

```
RaiseError(@Message, false, @null, @null, 1)
```

---

**EDIT 2020-11-24:** Adding in caveats from the comments for better visibility as it affects the answer.

It seems as though the **function does not allow for null values**, so you should instead find an API error code and API error number that makes sense for your example.

For example: `error 7000, Email failed validation: [validation error]`.

You can find a list of API errors **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error_codes.htm)**

Sample of final RaiseError call:

```
RaiseError(@Message, false, "Email Failed Validation", 7000, 1)
```

Comment: using the the line of code you provided but getting this :

Comment: The function expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
 Script: RaiseError(@ Message, false, @ null, @ null, 1)
 Index: 22
 ListID: 0
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a RaiseError function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter.
 Function Name: RaiseError
 Parameter Name: ErrorCode
 Parameter Ordinal: 3
 Parameter Type: Numeric
 Submitted Value: 
 ClientID: 7297215
 JobID: 0
 ListID: 0
 BatchID: 0
 SubcriberID: 262692048
 Data Source Type: CustomObject
 Data Source ID: b5671a1f-ff8d-e711-b071-38eaa71585b9

Comment: Do I need to initital the @ null variables to 0 or Null first?

Comment: No AMPscript variables that have not been initialized should default to a null value. It seems as though the function does not allow for null values, so you should instead find an API error code and API error number that makes sense for your example. For example, error 7000, Email failed validation: [validation error]. You can find a list of API errors [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error_codes.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and in classic Marketing Cloud fashion, the solution seems to be something that makes no sense. You have to SET whatever Data Extension function you want to persist even if the RaiseError is triggered.

So, instead of...

```vb
UpsertDE('ENT.Presend Agreement Error Log',1,
           'email_name',emailname_,
           'error_message',@Message)
```

Use...

```vb
SET @UpsertSomething = UpsertDE('ENT.Presend Agreement Error Log',1,
           'email_name',emailname_,
           'error_message',@Message)
```

...and the data will be retained, even when the RaiseError cancels the send.